# Convert file containing abstract tree

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have a [file](https://gist.github.com/gmile/57fb647c3f62ef052b28bf72e8275455) that contains an abstract tree, generated from a real code.

I want to:

1. read the file contents,
2. **convert the contents into list of actual terms**,
3. run a function (`compile:forms`) on the terms.

How do I do #2 from the list above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [file:consult/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#consult-1) to read file and convert it into terms. However you need to add dot (.) to end of file first.